# Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD

Tags: java, android

I run my application on android studio but it dosen't run. it returns this, "Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD" and stops. My intel HAXM is installed and up to date. pls help solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you virtualization is turned on